# Audio problem: it says "dummy output" and i can't hear anything

Tags: sound, 22.04, bluetooth, pulseaudio, alsa

audio works only with bluetooth devices, neither if i connect something with aux it's been recognized.
I tried opening `alsamixer`
but it says this

```
ALSA lib confmisc.c:855:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:5178:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_inum returned error: File o directory non esistente
ALSA lib confmisc.c:422:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:5178:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: File o directory non esistente
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1334:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:5178:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: File o directory non esistente
ALSA lib conf.c:5701:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: File o directory non esistente
ALSA lib control.c:1528:(snd_ctl_open_noupdate) Invalid CTL default
impossibile aprire il mixer: File o directory non esistente
```

so I can't modify anything.
doing `cat /proc/asound/cards` it says `no soundcard`
but if I run `lspci | grep -i audio`, it says:

```
0000:00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller (rev 20)
```

running this `aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav`
the terminal says that it's playing but I can't hear anything (i can only if I repeat the process connected to a Bluetooth device)
if I run `pulseaudio`, it says:

```
E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create() non riuscita.
```

I can't switch device in settings because the only output available is "dummy output"

Comment: "i tried a cuple of things i found online" to save people trying to provide answers you have already tried, [edit] you question with what you have actually tried. For example, in `Settings > Sound > Output` did you select an alternate from the drop down? That works for me when I have a bluetooth headset selected but then switch it off. The Output needs to be reset to the output device you then want.

Comment: Please don't edit your question to add "solved". When you can, accept your own answer. That is enough to mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 0):

i solved!

I have done

```
sudo apt remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio
```

And then I have installed again

```
sudo apt install alsa-base pulseaudio linux-sound-base
```

and

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop-minimal
```